# Must I set HSQLDB SA password every time whenever I restart HSQLDB server?

Tags: passwords, hsqldb

I started HsqlDB in server mode and set password for administrator account SA. Then I shutted down the server. Then I started the server again, but the password was gone. Must I set HSQLDB SA password again every time whenever I restart HSQLDB server? How to make the password set automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password (in latest versions, the password hash) is stored in the .script file. But you should perform CHECKPOINT after you set the password, otherwise it is may not be saved in some versions.